# Getting "connection is closed by foreign host" when I use JSch to transfer file from a remote machine

Tags: java, file, sftp, jsch, transfer

I'm trying to use JSch to transfer files from a remote machine,  whenever I execute the code I get the exception "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: connection is closed by foreign host". My code is given below, it doesn't even print "session established", so I thing the problem is at seeion.connetct();
Please help.

```
    String SFTPHOST ="hostname";
    int    SFTPPORT = 23;
    String SFTPUSER = "user";
    String SFTPPASS = "passwrd";
    String source   ="source file";
    Stirng dest     ="destination";   

    Session     session     = null;
    Channel     channel     = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

    try{
                JSch jsch = new JSch();
                session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER,SFTPHOST,SFTPPORT);
                session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
                session.connect();
                System.out.println("session connected...");
                channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
                channel.connect();
                System.out.println("channel connected...");
                channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
                channelSftp.get(source,dest);
                System.out.println("Transfer completed");
    }catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Ssh normally runs on port 22, not 23. Are you sure you're connecting to the right port? Assuming you are, you should inspect the log on the remote system to see why sshd is deciding to close the session.